Формула не считывает переменную, которая принимает значение из Excel-файла
Ситуация такая:
Из Excel-файла подтягиваются данные, присваиваются переменным:
book1 = openpyxl.open('BuhReport.xlsx', read_only=True)
sheet1 = book1.active

A1110_1 = float((sheet1[5][2].value))
A1110_2 = float((sheet1[5][4].value))
A1110_3 = float((sheet1[5][6].value))
A1110_4 = float((sheet1[5][8].value))
A1110_5 = float((sheet1[5][10].value))

A1120_1 = float((sheet1[6][2].value))
A1120_2 = float((sheet1[6][4].value))
A1120_3 = float((sheet1[6][6].value))
A1120_4 = float((sheet1[6][8].value))
A1120_5 = float((sheet1[6][10].value))

A1130_1 = float((sheet1[7][2].value))
A1130_2 = float((sheet1[7][4].value))
A1130_3 = float((sheet1[7][6].value))
A1130_4 = float((sheet1[7][8].value))
A1130_5 = float((sheet1[7][10].value))

и так далее.
Вот эта формула прекрасно считывает значения переменных:
def credit_ratio () :

    if combobox2.get() == ('2 периода') :

         book1 = openpyxl.open('BuhReport.xlsx', read_only=True)
         sheet1 = book1.active

         KAY1 = float((A1240_1 + A1250_1) / P1500_1)
         KAY2 = float((A1240_2 + A1250_2) / P1500_2)

         KTY1 = float((A1240_1 + A1250_1 + A1230_1) / P1500_1)
         KTY2 = float((A1240_2 + A1250_2 + A1230_2) / P1500_2)

         KOY1 = float((A1240_1 + A1250_1 + A1230_1 + A1210_1) / P1500_1)
         KOY2 = float((A1240_2 + A1250_2 + A1230_2 + A1210_2) / P1500_2)

А вот такая формула почему-то не видит переменные, выдает ошибку "cannot access local variable '...' where it is not associated with a value":
def financial_stable () :

    if combobox2.get() == ('2 периода') :

        book1 = openpyxl.open('BuhReport.xlsx', read_only=True)
        sheet1 = book1.active

        SOS1Y = float(P1300_1 -  A1210_1 - A1100_1)
        SOS2Y = float(P1300_2 -  A1210_2 - A1100_2)

        SDI1Y = float(P1300_1 - A1210_1 - A1100_1 + P1400_1)
        SDI2Y = float(P1300_2 - A1210_2 - A1100_2 + P1400_2)

        OIZ1Y = float(P1300_1 - A1210_1 - A1100_1 + P1400_1 + P1500_1)
        OIZ2Y = float(P1300_2 - A1210_2 - A1100_2 + P1400_2 + P1500_2)

Переменные заданы в самом начале. Прошу подсказать мою ошибку. Спасибо!

Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Воспользуйтесь global
